# OL3 overlay not displaying - appendChild error

Tags: javascript, overlay, openlayers-3

I have an OL3 application which displays map overlays but I have found in version 3.20 they no longer display.

My console log gives the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Below is the code I use; when the user enters two values and clicks on a button, it will retrieve these values and zoom the map to the coordinates, but it does not display my overlays. Do I need to alter this code in some way?

```
//Zoom map on coordinate zoom button click
$("#coord-zoom-btn").click(function() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('coord-x').value);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById('coord-y').value);
    map.setView(new ol.View({
        projection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:27700'),
        resolutions: [28.0, 14.0, 7.0, 3.5, 1.75, 0.875, 0.4375, 0.21875, 0.109375],
        center: [x, y],
        resolution: 0.21875
    }));
    if (coordinateMarker && coordinateLabel != null) {
        map.removeOverlay(coordinateMarker);
        map.removeOverlay(coordinateLabel);
    }
    coordinateMarker = new ol.Overlay({
            position: [x, y],
            positioning: 'center-center',
            element: $('<img src="img/marker/icon_coordinates.png" alt="Coordinate marker position">')
        }),
        coordinateLabel = new ol.Overlay({
            position: [x, y],
            positioning: 'center-center',
            offset: [0, -20],
            element: $('<h6>X: ' + x + ' Y: ' + y + '</h6>')
        })
    map.addOverlay(coordinateMarker);
    map.addOverlay(coordinateLabel);
});
```

Comment: + you better give us which line of code made the console error

Comment: Found the answer in this thread https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188865/error-with-popup-overlay-in-openlayers-3